# Binding position of popup to active textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position

I'm trying to figure out how to set the top and left values relative to the selected_element (active at the time of the popup triggering) similar to a tooltip. I've tried using $().position() with jQuery but that doesn't override the default 0,0 that I have set with CSS.

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sethkillian2/cd6agg73/3/
Hold down a, c, e, i, o, or u to trigger the menu.

Also, here's part of my attempt:

```
 $(popup).position({
  of: $(activeElement),
  my: 'left top',
  at: 'left top',
  offset: '0 0'
});
$('body').append(popup);
```

Changing the position attribute to anything besides absolute doesn't seem to work either because then the character menu expands. I've also tried getting the element by the ID directly after appending it using $("#charMap").position(...).

Update: For what it's worth, I've also tried using the textarea-caret-position component (https://github.com/component/textarea-caret-position) but that doesn't seem to be accurate.

Comment: Not certain what expected result is?

Comment: Charmap should appear above active textbox which is stored as activeElement.

Answer (score 0):

The `margin-top` and `margin-left` properties are set for `#ta` at CSS; you can use `.css()` to get and set the same properties for `popup`

```
$(popup).css($(activeElement).css(["marginTop", "marginLeft"]));
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cd6agg73/9/

Comment: The only problem with that is if there's a paragraph of text or something above it, then it doesn't work anymore. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't rely on the margins or padding, but rather the actual position.

Comment: What do you mean by "the actual position"? `var props = $(activeElement).css(["marginTop", "marginLeft"]);
     props.marginTop = parseFloat(props.marginTop) - ($(activeElement).height() * 2.5) + "px";
     $(popup).css(props);`? Or using `.getBoundingClientRect()` `var {top, left} = activeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
     $(popup).css({top, left});` https://jsfiddle.net/cd6agg73/12/ ? Which should render same result as code at Answer